# How to dynamically determine the selected item in a dropdownlist without viewbag, viewdata, or JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-select

Save I have an object `Mytype` which has an object `item` both have unique IDs, so ID1, and ID2.

I have an edit form and the data is loaded based on the ID of Mytype, ID1.

```
public void Load(int id)
{

    var db = new dbEntities();
    Mytypes = db.MyTypes.ToList();
    MyTypeList = new SelectList(Mytypes, "ID", "Name");
    // etc ....
```

I have a dropdownlist and would like it to land on the item with the same ID as the item ID (ID2) as the item belonging to Mytype with ID1.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("MyType_ID", Model.MyTypeList, 
         htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",
         required = "required", autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

Is it possible to do this without using `ViewBag` or `ViewData` or `JS`?

Comment: If `Mything` is a property in your model, then just sets its value to match one of the options and it will be selected.

Comment: `var model = new MyModel() { Mything = "ID2", MyList = ..... }; return View(model);` (but please use the strongly typed helpers - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Mything, Model.MyList, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })` (note your `required="required") is a bit pointless)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you model has a property named `MyType_ID`, then set its value to match one of the option value, at that option will be selected when the view is rendered

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string MyType_ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyTypeList { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and in the controller

```
MyModel model = new MyModel()
{
    MyType_ID = "ID2",
    MyTypeList = new SelectList(Mytypes, "ID", "Name")
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyType_ID", Model.MyTypeList, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

or preferably, use the strongly typed `xxxFor()` methods

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyType_ID, Model.MyTypeList, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })
```